# Why should @@class_variables be avoided in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class-variables, class-instance-variables

I know that some say that class variables (e.g. `@@class_var`) should be avoid in Ruby and should use the an instance variable (e.g. `@instance_var`) in the class scope instead:

```
def MyClass
  @@foo = 'bar' # Should not do this.
  @foo = 'bar'  # Should do this.
end
```

Why is the use of class variables frowned upon in Ruby?

Comment: I've quite recently read two books about Ruby and neither of them mentioned this so interesting to see what answers you'll get :)

Comment: See also [Difference between class variables and class instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802540/difference-between-class-variables-and-class-instance-variables).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Class variables are often maligned because of their sometimes confusing behavior regarding inheritance:

```
class Foo
  @@foo = 42

  def self.foo
    @@foo
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  @@foo = 23
end

Foo.foo #=> 23
Bar.foo #=> 23
```

If you use class instance variables instead, you get:

```
class Foo
  @foo = 42

  def self.foo
    @foo
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  @foo = 23
end

Foo.foo #=> 42
Bar.foo #=> 23
```

This is often more useful.

Answer (score 6):

Be careful; class `@@variables` and instance `@variables` are not the same thing.

> Essentially, when you declare a class
>   variable in a base class, it’s shared
>   with all subclasses. Changing its
>   value in a subclass will affect the
>   base class and all of its subclasses
>   all the way down the inheritance tree.
>   This behavior is often exactly what’s
>   desired. But equally often, this
>   behavior is not what was intended by
>   the programmer, and it leads to bugs,
>   especially if the programmer did not
>   originally expect for the class to be
>   subclassed by someone else.

From: http://sporkmonger.com/2007/2/19/instance-variables-class-variables-and-inheritance-in-ruby