# instance and class variables in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and ruby. I was studying the concept of class and instance variables. I understood the difference but when I tried it out using the controller in rails it got me confused. What I did is I declared a class and instance variables outside the class methods:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  # GET /books
  # GET /books.json

  @@world = "Hello World"
  @insworld = "my hobby"

  def index
    @books = Book.all
    binding.pry

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @books }
    end
  end

end
```

I was under the impression that @insworld has the value of "my hobby", but when I tried to check the value of @insworld when I was inside the `index method`, @insworld was returning a nil value. @@world has the value of "Hello World". So what happened here? Aren't they defined in the same class?

Comment: You might want to check the accepted answer for this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802540/difference-between-class-variables-and-class-instance-variables

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Classes are also objects in Ruby, so they can have their own instance variables which are called *class instance variables*.

- `@@world` is a *class variable*
- `@insworld` is a *class instance variable*
- `#index` is an instance method

When you try to access `@insworld` in `#index`, Ruby searches for the instance variable in the `A` object (meaning `A.new`) because `#index` is an instance method.

But you defined `@insworld` as a *class instance variable* which means it is defined in the class object itself (meaning `A`).

The following code demonstrates:

```
class Hi
  @@a = 1 # class variable
  @b  = 2 # class instance variable

  def initialize
    @c = 3 # instance variable
  end

  def test # instance method, works on objects of class Hi
    puts @@a # => 1
    puts @b  # => nil, there is no instance variable @b
    puts @c  # => 3 # we defined this instance variable in the initializer
  end
end

Hi.class_variables        # => @@a
Hi.instance_variables     # => @b
Hi.new.instance_variables # => @c
# Hi is an object of class Class
# Hi.new is an object of class Hi
```

Keep in mind that all instance variables return `nil` if they don't exist.

Answer (score 7):

When you declare `@instworld` you are inside BooksController class (i.e. `self` will return `BooksController`. Weird thing in ruby is that classes are also objects (the are instances of class `Class`) hence you in fact declares instance variable `@instworld` for this particular instance of class `Class`m not for instance of `BooksController`.

You can check it really easily by declaring class method:

```
class A
  # self here returns class A
  @variable = 'class instance variable'
  @@variable = 'class variable'

  def initalize
    # self here returns the instance
    @variable = 'instance variable'
  end

  def self.test_me
    # self here returns class A
    @variable
  end

  def test_me
    # self returns the instance
    @variable
  end

  #class variable is accessible by both class and instance 
  def test_me2
    @@variable
  end

  def self.test_me2
    @@variable
  end
end

A.test_me       #=> 'class instance variable'
A.new.test_me   #=> 'instance variable'
A.test_me2      #=> 'class variable'
A.new.test_me2  #=> 'class variable'
```

Answer (score 3):

When you declare instance variable outside of method, you might not get the result you want. It is an instance variable, yes, but it belongs to **the class itself** (which is an instance of class `Class`).

```
class Foo
  @myvar = "class-level"

  def initialize
    @myvar = 'instance-level'
  end
end

f = Foo.new

f.class.instance_variable_get(:@myvar) # => "class-level"
f.instance_variable_get(:@myvar) # => "instance-level"
f.instance_variable_get(:@myvar2) # => nil
```

If you try to get value of uninitialized ivar, it will evaluate to `nil`. That's why you got `nil` in your experiments: the variable doesn't exist at that scope.

To get instance-level variables, set them in methods/actions.

Answer (score 2):

The scope of Instance variables are from action to view they initiate when any action occurs and destroy when action ends.

Comment: so how do you have a true class instance variable, one that persists among all actions? @ahmad Hussain

Answer (score 2):

Declaring the @insworld within the class but not in the constructor or any of the instance methods sets  @insworld scoped to the instance of the class itself.

```
BooksController.instance_variable_get(:'@insworld')
```

If you need the access to variable inside of your index method, consider defining it within the method instead.