# Using HTTParty gem to make an endpoint (Rails5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, httparty

I'm a bit confused on how to handle this. Essentially I'm trying to learn more about Angular on Rails, so I'm using Rails in API Mode - However, currently, I'm trying to build an API into the non-API version of Rails I initiated (Not quite relevant, but I'm curious how to get it to work for both).

Very basic test off the bat, I'd like to his 
`/steam/:id` endpoint (in this example) and get the return for 
`GetPlayedSummaries`. HTTParty is installed, and working in terminal.

```
class SteamController < ApplicationController
  @steamKey = "{REDACTED}"
  @baseUrl = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key='+@steamKey+'&steamids='+@steamId+'"

  def get_player_summaries
    @steamId = params[:id]
    puts @baseUrl
    @games = HTTParty.get(@baseUrl).to_json
    puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
  end

end
```

This is my very basic controller. Realistically I have no reason to have steamKey separated but it helps encourage where I need help.

Originally I had `@baseUrl` as 
`@baseUrl = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=#{@steamKey}+'&steamids=#{@steamId}"`

With the full version I get a `bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)` pointing at the @baseUrl so I feel like I'm not including it properly. I'm working on that but even once it works I'm not quite sure how to make it so it just throws it out into the UI as pure JSON? I have this done with a lot of my other elements using JSON Builders etc, but that's DB Data. This is just an API call.

Insight/documents I can check out?

EDIT: I believe my issue regarding using `@steamKey` is related to [This SO Article.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311215/instance-and-class-variables-in-rails-controller) `@` is even being passed down to `get_player_summaries`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my edit, I was able to find the article to explain how to properly use URLs.

My working code is:

```
class SteamController < ApplicationController

  def initialize
    @steamKey = "{REDACTED}"
    @baseUrl = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key="+@steamKey+"&steamids="
  end

  def get_player_summaries
    @playerUrl = @baseUrl + params[:id]
    @games = HTTParty.get(@playerUrl).to_json
    puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
    render json: @games
  end

end
```

It's a bit slow on the response but could be an issue with C9.