# What are the scenarios when ruby creates a singleton class

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby. I have understood the singleton class concept of ruby but I have one question that at what point ruby creates a singleton class for objects. I mean when objects define their own method(which is not in its ancestor class or super class) or when the object is created at runtime. I am clear with the concept that when a Class or object define methods as their own methods an anonymous class inserted between the object and its class which is know as 'Singleton Class'. But looking at this thread [Difference between class variables and class instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802540/difference-between-class-variables-and-class-instance-variables?lq=1) in banister answer he has used something like

```
hello.singleton_class.class_variable_get(:@@class_var)
```

where hello is an object of a class `Hello` which has class variable `@@class_var`.
Why do we have to use 'singleton_class' in

```
hello.singleton_class.class_variable_get(:@@class_var)
```

Does the singleton class also get inserted when you define class variables in a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source code of `singleton_class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) you will find that it just forwards to the C-function `rb_singleton_class` (at least it does for MRI). If you [dive further](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/class.c#1498) into [that](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/class.c#1420) you will find some C-code that basically boils down to an elaborate set of tests for exceptional cases and then the singleton class is created if all goes well.

Conceptionally the `singleton_class` is just what its name suggests, a singleton `Class` object. As every well behaved singleton should it will be created when it is first *accessed*. Wether this happens because you define a singleton method or because you access `singleton_class` explicitly is entirely up to your program. For most objects there will never be a call to `singleton_class` and therefore the `Class` object will not be created at all. If that would not be the case it would hardly merit the overhead induced by the `singleton` mechanics.

I think the author of the answer you cite just wants to illustrate different possibilities of accessing the `@@class_var` class variable. Since `class_variable_get` is a method of class `Class` he will need an instance of that class and since the singleton class is implicitly derived from the regular parent class he can use it to. In the example he might also use

```
hello.class.class_variable_get(:@@class_var)
```

to the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for reference material. Its useful and gave in depth knowledge.

Comment: @Swapnil: In that case I would appreciate it if you accepted the answer or at least gave it an up vote.