# Class variables weird behavior

Tags: ruby

When I use `Class.new`, for some reason the class variables of the resulted classes interfere with each other:

```
# ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [i686-linux]

result = Class.new do
  p self # #<Class:0xb7cd5624>

  @@foo = 1
  def foo
    p @@foo
  end
end

result2 = Class.new do
  p self  # #<Class:0xb7cd54d0>

  @@foo = 2
  def foo
    p @@foo
  end
end

result.class_variable_set(:@@foo, 3)
result.new.foo   # expected 3, output 3
result2.new.foo  # expected 2, output 3
```

Why? What is happening under the hood?

Also there are related Warning messages but I am unable to understand what they mean, neither to find a good description.

```
warning: class variable access from toplevel
```

The closest clues I've found so far are:

> The access to the class variable is considered top level because the class keyword does not define a class name that would provide a scope to hold the class variable.

(c) http://japhr.blogspot.ru/2009/06/more-information-about-class-variables.html

> Since you're not creating a class with the `class` keyword, your class variable is being set on `Object`, not `Test`

(c) https://stackoverflow.com/a/10712458/1432640

Could somebody please describe in details why it happens and why it is so different from when I use `class` keyword?

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through it:

```
result = Class.new do
  p self # #<Class:0xb7cd5624>

  @@foo = 1
  def foo
    p @@foo
  end
end
```

At this point, `result` has been created as an instance of `Class` and the class variable for `Class`, `@@foo`, is set to 1.

```
result2 = Class.new do
  p self  # #<Class:0xb7cd54d0>

  @@foo = 2
  def foo
    p @@foo
  end
end
```

At this point, `result2` has been created as an instance of `Class` and the class variable for `Class`, `@@foo`, is set to 2.

```
result.class_variable_set(:@@foo, 3)
```

This sets the *class variable* in class `Class` with name `@@foo` to the value 3.

```
result.new.foo   # expected 3, output 3
```

Output is 3 because `@@foo` is set to 3 from the `class_variable_set` above.

```
result2.new.foo  # expected 2, output 3
```

`result2` has already been created before this statement occurs, so `@@foo = 2` is not executed. The construction above for `result2 = Class.new ...` created the instance already. `result2.new` creates a new instance of `Class`, and it exercises the constructor for `Class`, *not* the code you have above for `result2 = Class.new ...` (that had already been executed hen you constructed `result2`). The base `Class` constructor *does not know about `@@foo`* and doesn't use it or set it. So the value of `@@foo` is still 3.

---

Regarding the warning message:

> warning: class variable access from toplevel

you might want to Google search the warning message, as there are several good links to read. In particular, you might want to look at [The many gotchas of Ruby class variables](http://makandracards.com/makandra/14229-the-many-gotchas-of-ruby-class-variables). This brief article also explains what I'm describing above.

---

If you want to have separate class variables for your new, dynamically created classes, you can create/set the class variables *after* the class is created. You can name the classes by assigning them to a constant:

```
1.9.2-p330 :017 > result.class_variable_set(:@@bar, 3)
 => 3
1.9.2-p330 :018 > result2.class_variable_set(:@@bar, 4)
 => 4
1.9.2-p330 :019 > R1 = result
 => R1
1.9.2-p330 :020 > R2 = result2
 => R2
1.9.2-p330 :021 > class R1
1.9.2-p330 :022?>   def bar
1.9.2-p330 :023?>     p @@bar
1.9.2-p330 :024?>     end
1.9.2-p330 :025?>   end
 => nil
1.9.2-p330 :026 > class R2
1.9.2-p330 :027?>   def bar
1.9.2-p330 :028?>     p @@bar
1.9.2-p330 :029?>     end
1.9.2-p330 :030?>   end
 => nil
1.9.2-p330 :031 > R1.new.bar
3
 => 3
1.9.2-p330 :032 > R2.new.bar
4
 => 4
1.9.2-p330 :033 >
```

Comment: _At this point, result has been created as an instance of Class and the class variable for Class, @@foo, is set to 1._

I think this is where I'm stumbled. In the docs it is written: 

_Creates a new anonymous (unnamed) class ... (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-c-new)_

Therefore, its class variables should belong to this new anonymous (unnamed) class, shouldn't they?

Comment: @stillwaiting That's an excellent point. While the anonymous class is still unnamed and anonymous, the variable is common (part of the base `Class` object). If you named the new, anonymous class and created class variables in the classes by name, they would be separate. I'll update my answer to show that.

Comment: Thanks, but not sure I follow. You write _"If you want to have separate class variables for your new, dynamically created classes, you can create/set the class variables after the class is created."_, but this is what I'm doing: first I create an instance of a Class, and after that I'm trying to assign a class variable. If I remove "@@foo=1" from the block, nothing changes actually, the output is still the same. Neither if I assign the result or result2 to R1 or R2. I understand that everything runs smoothly with class block, but this is not the case I think. Am I missing somethinig?

Comment: @stillwaiting I'm distinguishing between *assigning* and *creating*. You *assigned* the class variable `@@foo` after creating the classes. I *created* the `@@bar` class variable *after* the new classes were created, not part of the `Class.new`.

Answer (score 0):

Class variables are shared throughout the class hierarchy. You might want to look into using [class instance variables](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) for your use case.

```
[42] pry(main)> class Parent
[42] pry(main)*   @@foo = "Parent"
[42] pry(main)*  end

[43] pry(main)>  class Thing1 < Parent
[43] pry(main)*    @@foo = "Thing1"
[43] pry(main)*  end

[44] pry(main)>  class Thing2 < Parent
[44] pry(main)*    @@foo = "Thing2"
[44] pry(main)*  end

[45] pry(main)> Thing1.class_eval("@@foo")
=> "Thing2"
[46] pry(main)> Parent.class_eval("@@foo")
=> "Thing2"
[47] pry(main)> Class.class_eval("@@foo")
=> "Thing2"
```

[Ruby, class variables and inheritance ? super class @@var gets changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909235/ruby-class-variables-and-inheritance-super-class-var-gets-changed)

Answer (score 0):

Blocks create a new nested lexical scope and close over their surrounding lexical scope. They do, however, *not* change dynamic scope.

Dynamic scope stays the same within the block as outside of it, i.e. the value of `self`, the value of the default definee, the current class.

Class variables at the top-level become class variables of `Object`. Moreover, the two blocks share the same outer scope. Therefore, they share the same class variables.

Note that *some* methods actually *do* change the dynamic scope of the block, e.g. `instance_exec` and `instance_eval` change the value of `self`.

Comment: Thanks. Wondering what "dynamic scope" is then? If I print "self", all they are different. Outside it prints "main", inside the first block it prints #<Class:0xb7cd5624>, in the 2nd one it is #<Class:0xb7cd54d0>....