# attr_accessor on class variable

Tags: ruby

```
class User 
  class << self
    attr_reader :passwordManagerAccountID
    attr_reader :masterPassword

    def session(passwordManagerAccountID , masterPassword)
      @@passwordManagerAccountID = passwordManagerAccountID
      @@masterPassword = masterPassword
    end
  end  
end

User.session("sdsd" , "sdsd")
User.passwordManagerAccountID #=> no output
User.masterPassword #=> no output
```

I am trying to use `attr_reader` on class variable but it doesn't seem to work.

I google searched but I don't seem to understand. So, if someone can explain me in simple terms the problem and its solution (**without using getter and setter methods**).

Comment: This may have also been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby
Did you really google search for this beforehand??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr_reader` just creates a method like this:

```
def masterPassword
  @masterPassword
end
```

So you either must access the correct class instance variable in `session` (e.g. `@masterPassword`) or forego using `attr_reader` and write your own accessor:

```
def masterPassword
  @@masterPassword
end
```

Unless you happen to have [ActiveSupport](http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) which does provide [`cattr_accessor`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Class.html#method-i-cattr_accessor), [`cattr_reader`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Class.html#method-i-cattr_reader), & [`cattr_writer`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Class.html#method-i-cattr_writer).

See also [Why should @@class_variables be avoided in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787154/why-should-class-variables-be-avoided-in-ruby/) for why you perhaps should just use class instance variables instead.

Comment: I know the difference, I want to know if its possible to use attr_access on class variables not instance variable.

like ruby on rails we can use cattr_accessor

Comment: @RushabhRajeshKumarPadalia No.

Comment: @RushabhRajeshKumarPadalia Yup.

Answer (score 0):

`attr_reader` is not reading class variables, but instance variables - you need to use class instance variables:

```
def session(passwordManagerAccountID , masterPassword)
  @passwordManagerAccountID = passwordManagerAccountID
  @masterPassword = masterPassword
end
```

Please mind the Ruby naming convention: it should be `password_manager_accound_id` and similar. There's no lowerCamelCase in Ruby.

Comment: Be careful saying “there’s no lowerCamelCase in Ruby”. There is, it’s just not the common convention. The Ruby syntax/interpreter doesn’t care, only developers do.

Comment: well, didn't know about the ruby naming convention, thanx